# Filter Array of Array of Dictionary and string

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, nspredicate

I have one array which contains array of dictionary and string
and I want to filter with dictionary value, 
but when I am doing filtering i am getting result only when I type first letter in text field i have written this code for nspredicate search
also I have attached screenshot for NSarry containing values which I uses for filtering.

Here is code for searching array:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;   // return NO to not change text
{

    NSString * searchStr = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSLog(@"%@",searchStr);
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@ ",searchStr];
    NSArray *filteredArr = [arrmainData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    detailListArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:filteredArr];
    [tblGlosary reloadData];

    return true;
}
```

Here is screensnap for array

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of mixed types (`NSString` and `NSDictionary`) which is generally a really bad idea (and won't be possible in Swift).

If you for some reason can't control this and really need to filter through it you need to check that you compare correctly depending on the type:

```
NSIndexSet *matches = [arrmainData indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:BOOL^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *stringToCompare = nil;

    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        stringToCompare = (NSString *)obj;
    } else {
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)obj;
        stringToCompare = dict["Name"];
    }

    return [stringToCompare rangeOfString:searchString].location != NSNotFound;
 }];

 NSArray *filteredArray = [arrmainData objectsAtIndexes:matches];
```

But again, if you can, really reconsider mixing types in the same array, it's likely going to lead to problems down the road.